# ProblemDetails doesn't serialize back to a ProblemDetails object

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have a REST service written in core 3.1.  When there is an error, I return a ProblemDetails object using the Problem() method in the controller.  When I run this through a Swagger UI, I get what I'm expecting.

```
{
  "isError": true,
  "responseException": {
    "exceptionMessage": {
      "type": "ApplicationException",
      "title": "Internal Server Error",
      "status": 500,
      "detail": "An Error Happened. I want this message to bubble up.",
      "instance": "/v1/TestAdapter/GetError",
      "traceId": "|31cf435b-44b49327cac802b2."
    }
  }
}
```

When I get this back from the service call, I want to serialize it back into a problem details object.  But that doesn't work.  I've been looking for what object that should serialize into.

I can do this and get the data.

```
var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But this doesn't work. (All fields are null.)

```
var typedBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProblemDetails>(responseText, new JsonSerializerSettings());
```

What should I be doing here to get that marshaled back into a ProblemDetails object?

Comment: What does ProblemDetails class look like?

Comment: ProblemDetails is supported by Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-3.1
You can also inherit from it and add more fields that are specific to your application.

Answer (score 0):

For serialization you need at least:

- An empty or default constructor - you have that one otherwise you will get an error
- settable properties. For System.Text.Json and JSON.net private settable properties will work. Read-only properties won't work. E.g.

```
public string WontWork { get; } 

public string DoesWork { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was of my own making.  I had installed a wrapper that was changing my return object.  I had installed it as a way of testing out the best way of getting error messages back to the caller.  In doing so, I created a return value that the client didn't know how to handle.